# Select the minimum value for each row join by another table

Tags: sql, join, group-by, multiple-tables, minimum

I have the following table:

```
           Table1                         Table2        
CardNo  ID   Record   Date          ID    Name      Dept    
1      101   8.00    11/7/2013      101   Danny     Green   
2      101   13.00   11/7/2013      102   Tanya     Red 
3      101   15.00   11/7/2013      103   Susan     Blue    
4      102   11.00   11/7/2013      104   Gordon    Blue    
5      103   12.00   11/7/2013                  
6      104   12.00   11/7/2013                  
7      104   18.00   11/7/2013                  
8      101    1.00   12/7/2013                  
9      101   10.00   12/7/2013                  
10     102    0.00   12/7/2013                  
11     102    1.00   12/7/2013                  
12     104    3.00   12/7/2013                  
13     104    4.00   12/7/2013
```

i want the result to be like this:

```
Name    Dept    Record
Danny   Green   8.00
Tanya   Red     11.00
Susan   Blue    12.00
Gordon  Blue    18.00
```

where the result is only showing the minimum value of "Record" for each "Name", and filtered by the date selected. I'm using SQL.

Comment: select min(record) from table where date ='wateverdate' group by name?

Comment: Can you please double-check your example? And/or explain why the last line in your result table has 18.00 instead of 12.00? If you were to filter for 12/7/2013, would you expect values 1.00, 0.00, NULL, 3.00?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use:

```
select t2.Name, t2.Dept, min(t1.Record)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
group by t2.ID, t2.Name, t2.Dept
```

or

```
select t2.Name, t2.Dept, a.record
from table2 t2
join
(
    select t1.ID, min(t1.Record) [record]
    from table1 t1
    group by t1.ID
)a
on a.ID = t2.ID
```

For filtering add `where` clause, e.g.:

```
select t2.Name, t2.Dept, min(t1.Record)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
where t1.Date = '11/7/2013'
group by t2.ID, t2.Name, t2.Dept
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
Select
    b.Name,
    b.Dept,
    MIN(Record) Record
from
    Table1 a join Table2 b on a.ID=b.ID
GROUP BY b.Name,
    b.Dept
```

Comment: OP asked for MIN, not SUM.

Comment: @Doug_Ivison Yeah! sorry. Thanks

Comment: Kirill, could you possible add some more syntax behind to select only the 'date' I want? example: where date = '11/7/2013'

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
        b.Name,
        b.Dept,
        min(a.Record)
from Table1 a,Table2 b 
where
        a.ID=b.ID 
group by 
        a.Record
```

Comment: The group by contains the columns that are *NOT* in aggregate functions, so:  `group by b.Name, b.Dept`